# Implement Quartz Scheduler in mule

Tags: java, mule, quartz-scheduler, esb, anypoint-studio

This is the first time i am trying to use a Quartz scheduler in Mule.
I am trying to schedule the start time of a flow based on the list of DateTimes  that i took from DB.

To study the working of a Quatrz scheduler and to schedule jobs based on a 'list of times' in java, i did the following sample.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.SimpleTrigger;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {
        List<SimpleTrigger> triggerList = scheduleMyJob();

        int i=0;

        for(SimpleTrigger trigger: triggerList){
            JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail();
            jobDetail.setJobClass(Hellojob.class);
            jobDetail.setName("MyJob"+ ++i);


            Scheduler jobScheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            jobScheduler.start();
            jobScheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        }
    }

    public static List<SimpleTrigger> scheduleMyJob(){
        List<SimpleTrigger> triggerList = new ArrayList<SimpleTrigger>();

        SimpleTrigger sTrigger = new SimpleTrigger();
        sTrigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+10000));
        sTrigger.setName("C Trigger 1");
        triggerList.add(sTrigger);
        sTrigger = new SimpleTrigger();
        sTrigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+20000));
        sTrigger.setName("C Trigger 2");
        triggerList.add(sTrigger);
        sTrigger = new SimpleTrigger();
        sTrigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+30000));
        sTrigger.setName("C Trigger 3");
        triggerList.add(sTrigger);
        sTrigger = new SimpleTrigger();
        sTrigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+40000));
        sTrigger.setName("C Trigger 4");
        triggerList.add(sTrigger);

        return triggerList;
    }

}
```

My helloJob.java looks like..

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class Hellojob implements Job {

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println(new Date() +": Hello Quartz World!! "+arg0.getJobDetail().getFullName());



    }

}
```

This works well, I got the following output

```
Sat Oct 24 15:41:47 IST 2015: Hello Quartz World!! DEFAULT.MyJob1
Sat Oct 24 15:41:57 IST 2015: Hello Quartz World!! DEFAULT.MyJob2
Sat Oct 24 15:42:07 IST 2015: Hello Quartz World!! DEFAULT.MyJob3
Sat Oct 24 15:42:17 IST 2015: Hello Quartz World!! DEFAULT.MyJob4
```

Now i understood the working of Quartz,but i have a hardtime relating the java code with the concept of Quartz in mule. I want to implement exactly the same thing in mule, and later i can replace the dates with those from DB. If you could guide me or show me an example, it will be of great help.
I only know about Quartz scheduler, if you got a different idea, you are always welcome...

*FYI. Hellojob will be replaced by a flow with a logger in it.*

[Tyring to implemant the logic in mule ended up no where.So i am not posting that code here since it may give a wrong assumtion of what my real target is!!. Java code above is a perfect example]

Answer (score 0):

To implement Batch Processing in Mule you can Mule Batch Processing Module which internally uses quartz scheduler and will make your life easier. You can assign CRON expression to schedule jobs. Please refer to the below mention docs to learn how Batch jobs works in mule.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/batch-processing

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/batch-streaming-and-job-execution